# Reliable way of finding out debian release name

Tags: shell, ubuntu, debian

I have a script that needs to know what is the release name of a debian system (example: trusty, sid, wheezy etc). I know that I can find out if I am on a Debian based system by looking for `/etc/debian_version`, but:

`cat /etc/debian_version`

`cat /etc/issue`

on Debian Stable produces:

`root@07156660e2cd:/# cat /etc/debian_version 
7.8
root@07156660e2cd:/# cat /etc/issue

Debian GNU/Linux 7 \n \l`

on Ubuntu produces:

```root@a81e3f32b147:/# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS \n \l

root@a81e3f32b147:/# cat /etc/debian_version 
jessie/sid
```

How I get Ubuntu's codename (in this case 'Trusty')? I don't want to have to maintain a dictionary of release versions to names please. Is there a way in the system to find this information out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `lsb_release`:

```
lsb_release -c
```

Answer (score 0):

@svlasov answer returns a little too much

lsb_release -sc returns just the code name

example

```
$ lsb_release -sc
utopic
```

Answer (score 0):

In docker images I can't use uname or another things. So I am using:

```
DEBIAN_RELEASE=$(awk -F'[" ]' '/VERSION=/{print $3}'  /etc/os-release | tr -cd '[[:alnum:]]._-' )
```

or not depending on /etc/os-release

```
awk -F'[" ]' '/VERSION=/{print $3}'  /etc/*-release | head -1 |tr -cd '[[:alnum:]]._-'
```

PS:

For docker images based on Debian I am using:

```
RUN export  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
     export DEBIAN_RELEASE=$(awk -F'[" ]' '/VERSION=/{print $3}'  /etc/os-release | tr -cd '[[:alnum:]]._-' ) &&
     echo "remove main from /etc/apt/sources.list" && \
     sed -i '/main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
     echo "remove contrib from /etc/apt/sources.list" && \
     sed -i '/contrib/d' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
     echo "remove non-free from /etc/apt/sources.list" && \
     sed -i '/non-free/d' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
     echo "deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian ${DEBIAN_RELEASE} main contrib non-free"  >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
     echo "deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian ${DEBIAN_RELEASE}-updates main contrib non-free"  >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
     echo "deb http://security.debian.org ${DEBIAN_RELEASE}/updates main contrib non-free"  >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    set -x &&\
    apt-get update
```